# Newtonsoft LowerCase Formatter not working

Tags: c#, json.net, asp.net-web-api2

I am using Web Api 2.

I have the following code in my WebApiConfig:

GlobalConfiguration.Configuration.Formatters.JsonFormatter.SerializerSettings.ReferenceLoopHandling = Newtonsoft.Json.ReferenceLoopHandling.Ignore;

```
        GlobalConfiguration.Configuration
          .Formatters
          .JsonFormatter
          .SerializerSettings
          .ContractResolver = new LowerCaseContractResolver();

        var json = config.Formatters.JsonFormatter;

        json.SerializerSettings.PreserveReferencesHandling = Newtonsoft.Json.PreserveReferencesHandling.Objects;
        config.Formatters.Remove(config.Formatters.XmlFormatter);
```

Where the section relating to LowerCaseContractResolver refers to:

```
   public class LowerCaseContractResolver : DefaultContractResolver
    {
        protected override string ResolvePropertyName(string propertyName)
        {
            return propertyName.ToLower();
        }
    }
```

I then want to convert a c# object with upper case names to a lower case JObject inside a JArray, as follows:

```
 string treeString = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(TreeViewLabelWithChildren);
 JObject treeJObject = JObject.Parse(treeString);
 JArray TreeJarray = new JArray();
 TreeJarray.Add(treeJObject);
 return TreeJarray;
```

The returned JArray still contains upper case names though. I Have tried applying the custom contract resolver in Application_Start() also. I can get this to work by applying the custom contract resolver inline, but would like a global way of setting this. Working inline:

```
var settings = new JsonSerializerSettings();
            settings.ContractResolver = new LowerCaseContractResolver();

string treeString = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(TreeViewLabelWithChildren, Formatting.Indented, settings);
```

Comment: Do not forget to use `ToLowerInvariant` instead of `ToLower`, as there are locales where the uppercase/lowercase mappings change (most notably turkish).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have just found the answer. I don't need to return a JArray, if I just return an array containing my C# object, then Web Api 2 will do the rest.